# I can not try Live CD

Tags: boot, live-cd

I inserted Boot CD into drive and choose "try", but monitor appears many horizontal lines passing through.
My laptop is WolfNFox, win XP SP1.
Can you help me?

Comment: Probably it is a graphics card issue,  retry it once more ,If it wont work remove the graphics card and retry .it

Comment: Cam you post the hardware specs of your machine.

Comment: there can also be a problem with the cd. try a live usb

Comment: Or you just might just haven't waited enough. It takes a while to load the GUI and all that stuff. I guess the maximum should be around 2min from cd and 40sec from USB.

Comment: Ohh, initially, my boot CD is OK, I can choose the language and then press try Ubuntu without installing. But after that, there are  only lines passing through. I did wait for around 5 minutes but the Ubuntu desktop did not appear on the screen. I already checked the boot CD and no error was found. Please help me.

Comment: just try in another way means make a bootable pen drive with your ubuntu and then try to install

Answer (score 0):

You can select "nomodeset" parameter from [boot options](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions) and try to install.